# Spring Webflux: Controller return Mono<ResponseEntity<MyPojo>> vs Mono<MyPojo>

Tags: java, spring-webflux

Question regarding return types I have seen with Spring Webflux.

In many examples, like online tutorials, the rest web controller of a Spring Webflux project will return a `Mono<MyPojo>`:

```java
    public Mono<MyPojo> monoPojo(String parameter) {
        return WebClient.create("http://...").get().retrieve().bodyToMono(MyPojo.class)
                .map(oneMyPojo -> unregisterRepository.insert(oneMyPojo));
    }
```

But I am also bumping into projects where it returns `Mono<ResponseEntity<MyPojo>>`:

```java
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<MyPojo>> monoResponseEntityPojo(String parameter) {
        return WebClient.create("http://...").get().retrieve().bodyToMono(MyPojo.class)
                .map(oneMyPojo -> unregisterRepository.insert(oneMyPojo))
                .map(ResponseEntity::ok);
    }
```

What are the benefits of `Mono<ResponseEntity<MyPojo>>` over `Mono<MyPojo>`?

Comment: ResponseEntity allows you to get status and whatever else ResponseEntity gives you. Actually though, you should use ServerResponse from the functional endpoints since ResponseEntity is from the servlet mvc lib (if I remember right). https://spring.getdocs.org/en-US/spring-framework-docs/docs/spring-web-reactive/webflux/webflux-fn.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Lets clear some things up

A `ResponseEntity<T>` is from the `org.springframework.http`package while a `ServerResponse` is from the `org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server` package.

This should as a start should give you a hint of when to use what, and where.

But in short, you can use webflux in 2 ways, either by using old fashioned `@RestController` annotations, with annotated functions for each path. This a sort of "backwards compatibility mode" between regular servlet spring web, and webflux async event driven programming.

`ResponseEntities` are returned from old `spring-web` while if you instead opt in to use functional enpoints that exist in webflux, you need to return `ServerResponses`.

If you look in the code for the classes you will se that they work some parts the same, but other parts differently, especially how they store the body and serialize the bodies.

`Handler functions` and `Filter functions` in webflux only work with `ServerResponses`.

Now to your question, returning `Mono<ResponseEntity<T>` or `Mono<T>`.

**Well it all comes down to how lazy you are.**

If you return a `Mono<T>` the framework will try to figure out what type of content you have in the `Mono`, and then create a `ResponseEntity` accordingly. So if you are serializing it into json, it will set the `content-type` for you, and set the status usually to `200 OK`

While if you wish, you can build your `ResponseEntity` completely custom, and return any status code, with any body, and any headers etc. etc.

So what it all comes down to is how lazy are you, how much do you want the framework to do for you, and how much to do you want to be explicit, and and type out everything by yourself, or customize.

Me, im lazy, i just return something that works.

Comment: Lazy is good!!!